# Can't find source of TLS 1.0 connection to AWS API

Tags: amazon-web-services

We recently received a notification from AWS about the following connection to the CloudWatch log endpoint from our AWS account using TLS v1.0 (which goes out of support next year):

```
Region | Endpoint | API Event Name | TLS Version | Connection Count | UserAgent
eu-west-1 | logs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com | DescribeLogStreams | TLSv1 | 1 | aws-sdk-dotnet-35/3.1.2.7 aws-sdk-dotnet-core/3.3.14.0 .NET_Runtime/4.0 .NET_Framework/4.0 OS/Microsoft_Windows_NT_6.2.9200.0 ClientSync
```

I've been having trouble tracing the source of the connection. I looked at our [CloudWatch logs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/tls-1-2-required-for-aws-endpoints/#:%7E:text=What%20should%20you%20do%20to%20prepare%20for%20this%20update%3F), but couldn't find any requests using TLS 1.0 -- though I don't know whether log requests would be, well, logged. None of our applications interact with any AWS APIs. We have several AWS instances and load balancers, and a couple of S3 buckets which are empty and haven't been used for some time. My searches for 'Microsoft_Windows_NT_6.2.9200.0 ClientSync' suggest that it might be something to do with the latter, but as I say, I know of no recent direct interaction with S3.

Any thoughts or advice around where to look would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure how you arrived at S3 from `Microsoft_Windows_NT_6.2.9200.0 ClientSync`. That is not the same as the `aws s3 sync` command. I can't actually find any info on that in my searching. As best I can tell, you have a Windows server sending logs to CloudWatch logs, and the logs agent on that server needs to be updated.

Comment: In the Console, open CloudTrail, go to Event History, and search for the event name "DescribeLogStreams". That will show you all of the calls to that API in the last 90 days, and you can open each and look for "tlsDetails". To make it a little easier (so that you don't look at events from the same source), you can go into the settings on that page and turn on "Source IP address".

Comment: It's also worthwhile to configure CloudTrail to write to an S3 bucket and/or CloudWatch Logs, because then you can use Athena or CloudWatch Logs Insights to do searches. Be sure to enable for all regions, and cross-organization (from the root account) if you're using orgs.